# Get specific XML tag text using Java in Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I've been trying to use XmlResourceParser but I don't feel it's the right tool for the job. I have a set of items that have subitems and I want to pull a specific item out, such as the second item in this list:

```
<story>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>The First Room</name>
    <description>You aren't sure how you ended up here, but there is nothing in this room of interest. You should probably escape.</description>
    <direction>
        <name>North</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </direction>
    <direction>
        <name>East</name>
        <id>3</id>
    </direction>
</story>
<story>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Moldy Room</name>
    <description>This room is filled with mold. It would be hazardous to your heath to stick around here.</description>
    <direction>
        <name>South</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </direction>
    <direction>
        <name>West</name>
        <id>4</id>
    </direction>
</story>
```

I'd like to be able to pull them by "id" number in short, WITHOUT having to set up my own objects. If possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
        Resources res = activity.getResources();
        XmlResourceParser xpp = res
                .getXml(R.xml.myxml);
        xpp.next();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        eventType = xpp.next();
        eventType = xpp.next();
        eventType = xpp.next();

        short id = Short
                .parseShort(xpp.getText());

        Toast.makeText(
                activity.getApplicationContext(),
                "" + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
```

Comment: This is close, but I want to be able to pull all the data for a specific "story" which may not be the first one, using the ID as the identifier, like a primary key.

Comment: I ended up having to move it into objects to get what I wanted done, but this answered the basic question. If anyone has future problems like this, you're going to HAVE to unmarshal your XML into objects.